# Using cached JS Bundle when URL same, but Query String different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, bundling-and-minification

My site does not seem to use the cached JS/CSS files when the query string parameter changes.

When the user navigates the site, they go through a sequence of "pages"

- www.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id?Indx=1
- www.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id?Indx=3
- www.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id?Indx=4
- www.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id?Indx=2
- www.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id?Indx=6

Between each transition, there is a post to the Controller-Action.

I would like to be able to use the cached version of the LESS / CSS / JS files when the user hits the page after the first time (its always the same files).

However, it seems - because the Query string parameter (Indx) is different - the entire bundle is called from the server again & the CDN is also hit again.

This seems counter-productive. Is there a way out of this mess?

I am sending over my JS / LESS files as a minified bundle or I am using a CDN (for JQuery etc). For the minified bundles, in the cshtml file, I calling them using "Styles.Render"

Any insight would be great! Thanks!